# Connecting BIRT to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, birt

I need to connect BIRT to google analytics and BIRT says they have a plugin. However, the only plugin i've found is outdated. What is the easiest/ most efficient way to connect BIRT to google analytics?
Thanks!